# How to fix buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'float32_t' but got 'double'

Tags: python, numpy, sse

I am trying to run the example code on this repo: [logsumexp](https://github.com/rmcgibbo/logsumexp).

However, when I run the example code:

```
import sselogsumexp
x = np.random.randn(100)
sselogsumexp.logsumexp(x)
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "sselogsumexp.pyx", line 8, in sselogsumexp.logsumexp (sselogsumexp.c:1258)
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'float32_t' but got 'double'
```

How can I convert a `double` to `float32_t`?

Comment: You can set the dtype using the [`.astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html#numpy-ndarray-astype) method. But are you sure you want floats instead of 64 bit doubles?

Comment: I know that this package only works with 32 bit. That solution worked. Thanks!